# My simple implementation of a DI container [open]

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine, dependency-injection, c#-7.0

I decided to make my own light DI container.

I know about Zenject, etc. I wanted a very light analog.

I'm concerned about a few things:

1) is it correct to use struct instead of class for reference in this context?

2) every time you access _player.Reference, there is a check for null (in the UnityEngine.After the destruction of the Object does not equal null, so use SafeIsUnityNull)

3) Double point. Can I overload the operator so that instead of `_player.Reference.AAAAAAAAAAAAA();`, it works `_player.AAAAAAAAAAAAA();` ??

Container itself:

```
    public static class DIContainer
    {

        private static readonly Dictionary<System.Type, Object> _references = new Dictionary<System.Type, Object>();

        public static void Bind<T>(T value) where T : Object
        {

            _references[typeof(T)] = value;

        }

        public static T Resolve<T>() where T : Object
        {

            if (_references.TryGetValue(typeof(T), out Object value))
                return (T)value;

            throw new System.InvalidCastException($"DIContainer: invalid resolve object {typeof(T)}");

        }

    }
```

Field reference:

```
    public struct DIReference<T> where T : Object
    {

        private T _reference;
        public T Reference => !_reference.SafeIsUnityNull() ? _reference : _reference = DIContainer.Resolve<T>();

    }
```

Installer:

```
    public abstract class SceneInstaller : MonoBehaviour
    {
        private void Awake() => InstallBindings();
        protected abstract void InstallBindings();

    }
```

```
public class LevelInstaller : SceneInstaller
{


}
```

**Using**

Bind:

```
    [SerializeField] private PlayerController _player;

    protected override void InstallBindings()
    {

        DIContainer.Bind(_player);

    }
```

Reference:

```
public class Test
{

    private DIReference<PlayerController> _player;

    private void Foo()
    {

        _player.Reference.AAAAAAAAAAAAA();

    }

}
```

Comment: No, you can't overload the member access operator `.` (thank god). Also I don't know if stackoverflow is the right place for this, maybe you want to post this on CodeReview? There doesn't seem to be any problem here. I have some things to say about your design but this is perhaps not the best place.

Comment: @RicardoPieper Thank you for your feedback! I am interested in any comments. I'm new and didn't know about CodeReview, so I'll create a theme there :)

Comment: Well, I gonna say it here anyway. I would question whether what you're doing is correct. I suppose I could run into a situation where I want an object of type T but none have been  `.Bind(obj)` yet. This could make your app explode for no reason, since the call to .Bind() would happen later anyway. Now you have to be careful yourself about the order things are initialized, instead of relying on the compiler (or a DI-that-works-automatically solution)

Comment: A much cooler problem to solve is to really solve the dependency graph and make things run in the correct order. I believe this can be limited in scope and lightweight, which are things you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few points:

- You cannot specify a constraint as `where T : Object`, since every type derives directly or indirectly from `System.Object`; however, you can enforce reference types with `where T : class`.
- You cannot overload the dot operator; however, you can overload the `explicit` and `implicit` operators:

  ```
  public struct DIReference<T> where T : class
  {
      private T _reference;
      public T Reference => !_reference.SafeIsUnityNull()
          ? _reference
          : _reference = DIContainer.Resolve<T>();

      public static implicit operator T(DIReference<T> reference) => reference._reference;
  }
  ```

  This allows you to do things like

  ```
  _player.Reference.AAAAAAAAAAAAA();

  // Implicitly convert from DIReference<PlayerController> to PlayerController:
  PlayerController pc = _player; 
  pc.AAAAAAAAAAAAA();

  //or

  ((PlayerController)_player).AAAAAAAAAAAAA();
  ```

  By instead overloading `explicit`, you are forced to use the last variant.
- Mutable structs are nasty. Your struct is read-only but not immutable. When accessed from a collection, you get a copy of the original struct, and all the changes to this copy are not written back to the original value in the collection.

  Let's assume that you have a `List<DIReference<T>> refList`. If now you write `var ref = refList[i].Reference;` then the newly resolved reference will not be stored back to `refList`!. You must write:

  ```
  var diRef = refList[i];
  var ref = diRef.Reference; // May resolve the _reference field from DIContainer!
  refList[i] = diRef;
  ```